# Can't connect to Android Wear watch after a reboot

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

After the watch reboot, changing a watch face from `AndroidWear` application works, but companion application can't communicate with a watch for some reason.

Although the question isn't specific enough (there's nothing to share in terms of code), maybe someone has experienced such case?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to double check if your Bluetooth is properly paired between the two device. Because one of the most common reasons for an Android Wear device refusing to talk/pair to your phone is the Bluetooth, by having too many devices paired with it.

Source: [ANDROID WEAR PROBLEMS AND SOLUTIONS](https://www.androidpit.com/android-wear-problems-and-solutions)

Another possible solution to your problem is found in this [Android Wear Help](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6057772?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=0) support page.

Here are the things that you need to know.

- Make sure your phone and Google apps are up-to-date
- Bluetooth is turned on
- Phone Internet connection